# Getting the warning "cast to pointer from integer of different size" from the following code

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

The code is:

```
           Push(size, (POINTER)(GetCar(i) == term_Null()? 0 : 1));
```

Here  is the   `C code push` returns  `ABC` which is

```
 typedef POINTER  *ABC
 typedef void * POINTER
 ABC size;
 Push(ABC,POINTER);
 XYZ GetCar(int);
 typedef struct xyz *XYZ;
 XYZ term_Null(); 
 long int i;
```

What is the reason for the particular warning?

Comment: is sizeof(int)==sizeof(void*) on your platform?

Comment: no the size of **int** and size of **void pointer ** are different. So i am using **long int**.

Comment: so what do you not understand about the message? you're casting an int to a pointer type, you know they have different sizes, and the message tells you that again. seems pretty clear, no?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use `intptr_t` to ensure the integer has the same width as pointer. This way, you don't need to discover stuff about your specific platform, and it will work on another platform too (unlike the `unsigned long` solution).

```
#include <stdint.h>

Push(size, (POINTER)(intptr_t)(GetCar(i) == term_Null()? 0 : 1));
```

Taken from the C99 Standard:

> 7.18.1.4 Integer types capable of holding object pointers
>
> 1 The
>   following type designates a signed
>   integer type with the property that
>   any valid pointer to void can be
>   converted to this type, then converted
>   back to pointer to void, and the
>   result will compare equal to the
>   original pointer:
>
> intptr_t

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do? **Pointers are not integers**, and you are trying to make a pointer out of `0` or `1`, depending on the situation. That is illegal.

---

If you were trying to pass a pointer to a `ABC` containing `0` or `1`, use this:

```
ABC tmp = GetCar(i) == term_Null()? 0 : 1;
Push(size, &tmp);
```

Comment: i did the one you mentioned here. but still i am getting the same  warning. Can you please tell me what else can be the reason?

Comment: Can you give us the full warning, and a bigger chunk of code? You can pastebin them [here](http://paste.pocoo.org).

Comment: hi, I typecasted the **0** and **1** as long int, and it worked for me. Thanks for your help

Comment: `Push(size, &ABC);` is not a valid statement(ABC is a type, not a variable...)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to cast an integer value (0 or 1) to a void pointer.

This expression is **always** an int with value 0 or 1: `(GetCar(i) == term_Null()? 0 : 1)`

And you try casting it to void pointer `(POINTER)` (`typedef void * POINTER`).

Which is illegal.

Comment: This is __exactly__ what I said.

Comment: @nightcracker - I agree with your answer, but I saw your post after I posted mine.

Comment: MByD: Oh ok, I personally always click "Load new answers" :)

Answer (score 0):

Since this question uses the same typedefs as your 32bit to 64bit porting question I assume that you're using 64 bit pointers. As MByd wrote you're casting an int to a pointer and since int isn't 64 bit you get that particular warning.