# Dlsym: cast to pointer from integer of different size

Tags: c, dlsym

I really hate having to ask questions on here. But I've been looking at [some of the other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701450/getting-the-warning-cast-to-pointer-from-integer-of-different-size-from-the-fol), and solutions such as this one don't seem to work. Its probably my misunderstanding of the syntax.

I am improving some old code of mine. The function in questions cycles through some loaded modules and runs a function. This code worked perfectly well when I was on x86, but the jump to 64bit is screwing everything up.

```
int FindCmd(ArgS *Args)
{   
    /* We need to check our loaded modules for the appropriate command. */
    int found = 0;

    ModS *Current;

    for(Current = Modules; Current != NULL; Current = Current->Next)    
    {   /* Cycle through the modules. */

        int (*OnConsoleCmd)(RootS *IRC, ArgS *Args, McapiS *Mcapi);

        /* The below statement is the problem. */
        OnConsoleCmd = (int (*)(RootS *, ArgS *, McapiS *))dlsym(Current->Handle, "OnConsoleCmd");
        /* The above statement is the problem. */

        if(OnConsoleCmd != NULL)
        {
            if(OnConsoleCmd(IRC, Args, Mcapi) != 0)     /* Run command. */
                found++;
        }
    }

    return found;
}
```

I get the following warning:

```
exec/src/input.c:98:18: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
```

And of course my program segfaults. I know this is just a casting issue, but I don't know an easy and portable solution. If you need anymore informatioe, let me know. Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't hate asking questions on here, that is largely the purpose of this web site.

Comment: @dreamlax: There's a difference between hating to have to and hating to. Hating to have to means you're constructively dissatisfied with being inexperienced. Hating to means you're reluctant to ask for the help you actually need to improve.

Answer (score 3):

This is highly likely to be because you don't have a prototype for `dlsym()` in scope, and thus it is implicitly declared as `int dlsym()`, which is wrong.

If you add `#include <dlfcn.h>` to the file that uses `dlsym()`, you will get the correct declaration and it should work.

Comment: Yep, that's it, I forgot <dlfcn.h>. Wow, how embarrassing! Anyway, thanks!