# warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]

Tags: c, sockets, pointers, client-server

part of my code:

```
int server_sockfd, client_sockfd; //socket file descriptors of client and server

// ... some code 

if(pthread_create(&vlakno, NULL, handle_client, (int *) client_sockfd) != 0) {
            perror("Error while creating thread.");
        }
```

I'm getting **"warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]"**

prototype of  my function:

```
void *handle_client(void *args);
```

I found this question: 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701450/getting-the-warning-cast-to-pointer-from-integer-of-different-size-from-the-fo)

The first answer said something like that he should use intptr_t instead of int.
I have two questions:
**What is difference between int and intptr_t in my case? 

What should I do?** 
I have 2 ideas:
1st: (changing type of file descriptors)

```
 int server_sockfd, client_sockfd; //socket file descriptors of client and server

    // ... some code 

    if(pthread_create(&vlakno, NULL, handle_client, (intptr_t *) client_sockfd) != 0) {
                perror("Error while creating thread.");
            }
```

or 2nd idea: (changing type only in casting function pthread_create)

```
intptr_t server_sockfd, client_sockfd; //socket file descriptors of client and server

        // ... some code 

        if(pthread_create(&vlakno, NULL, handle_client, (int *) client_sockfd) != 0) {
                    perror("Error while creating thread.");
                }
```

EDIT:
 
in function handle_client i want to do this:

```
int clientSocket;
clientSocket = (int)args;
```

I'm really sorry to user cnicar or something like that .. he unfortunatelly deleted his answer but it was ok.

His solution was use (void *), it firstly casted same same error but it was caused probably bad behaviour of eclipse :(
So message for him:
Ok thanks it looks thats fine now ... Eclipse still throwed this warning but when I turned it on and off twice afer edit it fine with your edit :) thanks a lot

Comment: How about passing a pointer to the FD, as in `&client_sockfd`?

Comment: @KerrekSB please look at my edit if your suggestions is ok with that. ('m not sure when I'm using pointers)

Answer (score 8):

You have declared `client_sockfd` as an `int`. You shouldn't cast that to an `int *` that way.

Use the `&` operator, to get the address of `client_sockfd`, instead if you meant to give a *pointer* to `client_sockfd`:

```
pthread_create(&vlakno, NULL, handle_client, &client_sockfd)
                                          // ^ & operator
```

Do watch out for the lifetime of `client_sockfd`, it must outlive the thread to prevent race conditions (see the comments).

---

The difference between `int` and `intptr_t` is that `int` is meant to hold an integer, while `intptr_t` is meant to hold an address in form of an integer. `intptr_t` is guaranteed to be able to hold a pointer, while `int` is not.

If your intention was to pass the *value* of `client_sockfd`, cast it to an `intptr_t`:

```
pthread_create(&vlakno, NULL, handle_client, (intptr_t)client_sockfd)
```

Comment: Passing `&client_sockfd` **is not safe** unless you add synchronization to ensure that the caller does not return before the new thread uses the pointed-to value! OP's original code was correct despite the warning, and a useless cast through `uintptr_t` would avoid the warning.

Comment: To be clear: OP's version only has a bug on obscure compilers where `int`-to-`void *`-to-`int` round trip is not safe. As far as I know, no such compiler exists - certainly none exist which also support POSIX threads. On the other hand, your version has a serious race condition bug on every system out there.

Comment: @R.. in the same time C doesn't guarantee that an integer value is preserved after the *round trip* if it is an `int` and not a `uintptr_t` or an `intptr_t`.

Comment: @user1203803 I have a different situation and used your answer and the warning went away :)

I function `CreateWindowEx` the 10th argument required typecast to `HMENU` but only typecasting didn't work so I used this `(HMENU)&uWindowId` and problem solved.

Thanks man,

Answer (score 4):

```
(int *) client_sockfd
```

`client_sockfd` is not a pointer. It's an `int`, which is not the same size as an `int *`. And it's telling you that.

The last argument to `pthread_create()` is a `void *` and is meant to be a pointer to data that you want to pass into that particular thread. It appears you're trying to convert the  integer value of `client_sockfd` to a pointer and pass that. That's generally not something you would do, but if you *really* want to and avoid the warning then you need to use something that is the same size as a pointer, which is what `intptr_t` gives you. More than likely `int` is 4 bytes and `intptr_t` (and `void *`) is eight bytes on your system, but that is platform dependent. While you can safely go from 32->64->32 bits, the compiler is warning you that you have different sizes.

Comment: The last argument to `pthread_create` can also pass integer arguments as long as the value safely fits in `void *` via the implementation's conversion from `int` to `void *` to `int`.

Comment: Just because you *can* do something doesn't mean you should. That being said ... that's exactly what the last paragraph of my answer says. I'll add some clarity to explicitly talk about sizes.

Answer (score 0):

`(int *) client_sockfd` is not equivalent to `&client_sockfd`.

The first converts the value of `client_sockfd` to an `int *` and the second form yields a pointer to `client_sockfd`.

It is the latter expression you have to use for `pthread_create` last argument.

Comment: Passing `&client_sockfd` is incorrect and extremely unsafe unless you add synchronization to ensure its lifetime does not end before the new thread uses it. OP's code is correct despite the warning. You can eliminate the warning with a useless cast through `uintptr_t`.

Comment: @R.. Depending on how `handle_client` is implemented passing a copy of `client_sockfd` converted to a pointer type can be just wrong. Regarding the lifetime of the object `client_sockfd`, nothing in the OP question tells us that it doesn't have static storage duration or that the descriptor could be accessed in a unsafe manner.

Comment: I'm assuming it's not static because static storage duration for threads is just a formula for writing crap code. Actually the same would be true even without the phrase "for threads". I agree it's possible that the `handle_client` function is expecting a pointer, but I doubt it since OP asked the question about a warning and not about why `handle_client` is crashing...